# How to find other users near me?

Tags: angular, mongodb

I am building a job posting app that finds users around them that has posted also posted jobs. At the register, I will be getting users long and lat. I want to be able to find users near me and return the jobs that they posted. My MongoDB database looks something like

```
   {
     id:"hrjhjhhg278784ghsgha",
     first_name:"john",
     last_name:" doe"
     location: {
       lat:  34.5555,
       long: 45.333 
     },
     jobs_posted: [{}],
     jobs_completed: [{}],
     jobs_applied: [{}] 
   }
```

Currently, I am getting the geolocation and sending it in the system on the register in MongoDB. I want to be able to find users near me that have posted jobs and then load them up in my dashboard page. I need some guidance as to how I can implement this. Its a job posting app

Comment: https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript

Comment: Looks like you want to use the [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near) operator.

Comment: thank you I had no idea mongodb had near operator